# Why Does Powershell Occasionally Repeat Column Headers?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm running a disk partition audit on VMs using PowerCLI. Everything runs fine, however I noticed that in the output report, the column headers are occasionally repeated.

Example (export to CSV):

[image: example]

The code I've got is as follows:

```
$VMs = (Get-VM).where{$_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn' -and $_.Guest.OSFullName -match 'Windows'}

$vmErrors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$report = foreach ($VM in $VMs){
    $name = $vm.Name
    Write-Host "Retrieving data for $name... " -NoNewline
    try{
        $output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText @'
            Get-Disk | Foreach-Object{
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    ComputerName   = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                    BIOS           = if (Test-Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\control\SecureBoot\State) {"UEFI"} else {"Legacy"}
                    OS             = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select Caption -ExpandProperty Caption
                    Version        = [Environment]::OSVersion | Select Version -ExpandProperty Version
                    Number         = $_.number
                    Size           = [int]($_.size/1GB)
                    PartitionStyle = $_.PartitionStyle
                }
            } | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

'@ -VM $name -GuestUser $global:Username -GuestPassword $global:Password -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop

        if($output.ScriptOutput -match 'PartitionStyle')
        {
            $output.ScriptOutput -replace '(?s)^.+(?="Com)' | ConvertFrom-Csv
        }
        Write-Host "Done" -ForegroundColor Green
    }catch{
        $vmErrors.Add($name)
        Write-Host "Error!" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

$report | FT -AutoSize
```

I did notice that this started happening after I added the following lines, but maybe it's related to something else I'm not aware of?

```
BIOS           = if (Test-Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\control\SecureBoot\State) {"UEFI"} else {"Legacy"}
OS             = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select Caption -ExpandProperty Caption
Version        = [Environment]::OSVersion | Select Version -ExpandProperty Version
```

Comment: `Select Caption -ExpandProperty Caption` --> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption` and `Select Version -ExpandProperty Version` --> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version`

Comment: @Theo is probably right. In general; this happens if you (accedentilly) drop a different object (with different properties, or a `$Null`) in the pipeline.

Comment: @Theo I gave it a try with those changes, but the output was the same

Comment: @DougMaurer I replaced the parts per Theo's suggestion (`OS             = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption` & `Version        = [Environment]::OSVersion | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version`) and the output is exactly the same as what was in the post

Comment: I have no explanation, but note that [`Invoke-VMScript`](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/structures/vmware.vimautomation.vicore.types.v1.vm.guest.vmscriptresult/) accepts an _array_ of computer names, so you could try to get away with a single call, which _may_ make your problem go away.

Comment: From your image, it looks like you’ve cut&paste the report into excel - could you screenshot the actual formatted output from running the script in case there’s any clues in the whitespace / line breaks in the console?

Comment: @mclayton I actually have a line to export it into a CSV when it's done (to share the report with others), and that screenshot came right from it. I updated the post to clarify

Comment: Why not include that line to export to CSV within the question? So far I'm not reproducing this problem. What is the purpose of your `-replace` regex? Tried omiting it?